# CI insertion failed

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I was having a problem while registering a new user in **Code Igniter** and it failed. I some how managed to echo the query and when i run it manually on phpmyadmin, it gives me the following error
**#1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL error 1205 can occur when your application (in this case, PHP) dies in the middle of a transaction and the connection is not closed.

Restarting MySQL will fix the problem, but you should try finding out where the error is in your code. It should be in the PHP error log. If Code Igniter was able to catch the error (unlikely, given the circumstance) then it may be in `application/logs`.

If execution time might be the culprit, check [PHP: Runtime Configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php). Specifically:

`max_execution_time` and, additionally, [`memory_limit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)

Increasing these values (the amount of which, you'll have to experiment with) should eliminate script execution time as a potential issue. You can set these in your php.ini. Since you're using xampp, the location will be either `<installation drive/directory>\xampp\php` or `<installation drive/directory>\xampp\apache\bin`.

Hopefully this helps you resolve your question.

Answer (score 0):

this problem was on my local server, i am using xampp, but the query was running fine on dev server. May be there is some execution time issue with xampp. But the issue is fixed now. Thanks to all :)

Comment: My answer is still correct. I'm not sure why you unaccepted it. If the execution time exceeds the limit, that will cause it to die in the middle of the transaction, thus giving you the error...

Comment: i accepted it but i did not get the right answer, from where to exceed the execution time?